# Adding key value pairs to all objects

Tags: javascript, jsp

Im new to spring, I convert a object as json to use in jsp page. The json object looks like following.

```
[
    {"year":2014,"average":115.5},
    {"year":2016,"average":0.0},
    {"year":2017,"average":8.28},
    {"year":2018,"average":0.0}
]
```

I need to add another key value pair **( "color" : value )** to each object like given below.

```
[
    {"year":2014,"average":115.5,"color":1},
    {"year":2016,"average":0.0,"color":2},
    {"year":2017,"average":8.28,"color":3},
    {"year":2018,"average":0.0,"color":4}
]
```

Now I passed to page, how to add this key value pair to each objects in javascript?

Comment: [ { name: 'eve',
    isActive: true,
    timestamp: 2017-12-16T16:03:53.083Z },
  { name: 'john',
    isActive: true,
    timestamp: 2017-12-16T16:03:53.083Z },
  { name: 'jane',
    isActive: true,
    timestamp: 2017-12-16T16:03:53.083Z } ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your existing object like so:

```
var yourNewArray = yourOriginalArray.map(function(obj) {
    var me = Object.assign({}, obj);
    me.color = 'yourNewColorValue';
    return me;
});
```

Comment: This would indeed clone an object. Your comment regarding copying an answer however smells.